# I want to upload an image using https://storage.3d.io

Tags: html, aframe, archilogic, 3d.io

I want to store my product image in storage.3d.io website. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean the storage key? You can get it from the image URL, it's the last part:

`temp/2017-10-03_08-10-56_07HOnM/Hydrangeas.jpg`

You can then use it with the storage.3d.io prefix:

https://storage.3d.io/temp/2017-10-03_08-10-56_07HOnM/Hydrangeas.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Check https://3d.io/docs/api/1/storage.html

It has the necessary information you need

Comment: I am using this code

var el = document.getElementById('file-box')
io3d.utils.ui.fileDrop({
  elementId: 'file-drop-box',
  upload: true,
  dragOverCssClass: 'file-drop-box-dragover',
  onInput: function(key){
    io3d.utils.ui.alert(key)
    console.log(key)   
  }
})


and my image is uploaded in this path.(https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/archilogic-content-beta/temp%2F2017-10-03_08-10-56_07HOnM%2FHydrangeas.jpg)

how can i get image ID. plz you have any code example plz send me

Comment: what do you mean by "image ID"? You have the path to the uploaded file, no?